# How do I discard a record that throws an error?

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB query and I want the query to continue after one error and skip that record.

I get the following error:

> Error: getMore command failed: {
>      "operationTime" : Timestamp(1547144095, 335),
>      "ok" : 0,
>      "errmsg" : "Failed to parse objectId '' in $convert with no onError value: >Invalid string length for parsing to OID, expected 24 but found 0",
>      "code" : 241,
>      "codeName" : "ConversionFailure",
>      "$clusterTime" : {
>          "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1547144095, 335),
>          "signature" : {
>              "hash" : BinData(0,"aMqO7W+xnEbbUw6UsX/cxr2jxzo="),
>              "keyId" : NumberLong("6626865028530176001")
>          }
>      }
>   }

I don't want to fix the error, I just want to ignore it and want the query to continue. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming test data like:

```
 db.things.insert([{ myfield: ObjectId()}, { myfield:  "Some text"}])
```

You can avoid passing invalid field values by matching against the expected [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) of the value you are converting:

```
db.things.aggregate([
    { $match: {
        myfield: { $type: "objectId" }
    }},
    { $addFields: {
        converted: {
            $convert: { 
                input: "$myfield",
                to: "objectId",
            }
        }
    }},
])
```

Alternatively, you could set the `onError` value in `$convert` to something you can use in your aggregation pipeline (for example, with a `$match` or [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) expression):

```
db.things.aggregate([
    { $addFields: {
        converted: {
            $convert: { 
                input: "$myfield",
                to: "objectId",
                onError: 0
            }
        }
    }},
    { $match: {
        converted: { $ne: 0 }
    }}
])
```

Comment: Yes! That's what was happening. Thank you very much